# Cannot POST a file together with other form parameters

Tags: java, cxf, swagger

I am trying to post a file together with some rest parameters to my REST service. I defined the operation like this:

```
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@ApiImplicitParams(@ApiImplicitParam(dataType = "java.io.File", name = "image", paramType = "formData"))
@ApiOperation(value = "Create a car", notes = "Create a new car")
@Path("/new")
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Car created in the database"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Car was not created. Error processing the uploaded file")
})
Response createCar(
        @ApiParam(hidden = true, value = "image") List<Attachment> attachments,
        @ApiParam(value = "Token", required = true) @HeaderParam("Token") String token,
        @FormParam(value="model") String model
);
```

However I get an exception in the server when sending the request using swagger ui:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid URL encoding: not a valid digit (radix 16): -17

The weird part is that, if I remove the last parameter, everything goes fine and I receive the uploaded file. However, I need this extra form parameter in my method.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you show your request

Comment: I solved it (found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532034/apache-cxf-rest-multipart-upload-encoding-exception). CXF requires all parameters to be multipart in this case. Note: if also using swagger, you will need to set an implicit param for each of the parameters.